# Linking Customer's Old Orders placed as guest with new account created by customer later

Tags: magento-1.8, customer-account

I was having guest checkout enabled on my magento store, But later regular customers started orders using registering themselves to the store.

So Now i want to link their old orders(they ordered as guest) to their created accounts, They are using same email id they used previously when they ordered as guest.

I want this functionality because i want customers can see there all order history by their accounts.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. To show guest orders in Account Dashboard -> **RECENT ORDERS** you have
   to change `app/code/core/Mage/Sales/Block/Order/Recent.php` ->
   `public function __construct()`. Replace this:

   ```
   ->addAttributeToFilter('customer_id', Mage::getSingleton('customer/session')->getCustomer()->getId())
   ```

   with this:

   ```
   ->addAttributeToFilter('customer_email', Mage::getSingleton('customer/session')->getCustomer()->getEmail())
   ```
2. To show guest orders in **My Orders** change
   `app/code/core/Mage/Sales/Block/Order/History.php` -> `public function __construct()`. Replace this:

   ```
   ->addFieldToFilter('customer_id', Mage::getSingleton('customer/session')->getCustomer()->getId())
   ```

   with this:

   ```
   ->addFieldToFilter('customer_email', Mage::getSingleton('customer/session')->getCustomer()->getEmail())
   ```
3. To be able to **View** these orders you have to modify the controller too -> `app/code/core/Mage/Sales/Controller/Abstract.php` -> `protected function _canViewOrder` - change this:

   ```
   $customerId = Mage::getSingleton('customer/session')->getCustomerId();
   ```

   with this:

   ```
   $customerEmail = Mage::getSingleton('customer/session')->getCustomer()->getEmail();
   ```

   and this:

   ```
   if ($order->getId() && $order->getCustomerId() && ($order->getCustomerId() == $customerId)
   ```

   with this:

   ```
   if ($order->getId() && $order->getCustomerEmail() && ($order->getCustomerEmail() == $customerEmail)
   ```

It's not good to edit these files directly in core, at least you can copy them in local. Also there are other places that have to be changed if you want all functions to be available for there orders, like reorder and others, but it's a good start.

Comment: Thanks Michael, Let me try those solutions provided by you and will get back to you.

Comment: Thanks michael. Its working for me. It is showing orders to the customer but from admin it doesn't show order for that customer.

Comment: In the admin panel is more complicated. The file for **tab Customer View - Recent Orders** is `app/code/core/Mage/Adminhtml/Block/Customer/Edit/Tab/View/Orders.php` -> `protected function _prepareCollection()` and for **tab Orders** -> `app/code/core/Mage/Adminhtml/Block/Customer/Edit/Tab/Orders.php` -> `protected function _prepareCollection()` which are using `Mage::getResourceModel('sales/order_grid_collection')` which is using database table `sales_flat_order_grid` which doesn't have column **email**. That's why you have to make some joins or to change the table.

Comment: Your solution worked for me, no need for admin edits. Thanks again

Answer (score 1):

I agree with @michael, but for those who wants easy way, I have developed an extension for you.

[Check this link](http://www.magentocommerce.com/magento-connect/relate-customer-with-order.html).

Hope it helps someone.